# which return comply with C++ standard

Tags: c++

```
class A {};

class B 
{
public:
    B(const A& a, int i = 10) : m_a(a), m_i(i) {}
private:
    int m_i;
    A m_a;
};

B getB(void)
{
    //return B(A());  // Method one
    //return A();     // Method two
}
```

Both method one and method two pass the compilation of VS2010.

**Question 1**> Which one is better?

**Question 2**> Is it true that an implicit constructor supports more than one pass-in parameters if all except the first parameters have default values?

Thank you

Comment: How does the second one compile? `A()` is not of type `B`

Comment: @DanF: B has an implicit constructor from A. It works the same way you can pass a string literal for a `std::string const&`

Comment: Ah, I see, the constructor is implicitly called.  I was unaware that was accepted, I certainly wouldn't code that way

Comment: @DanF: I think you code that way without realizing it :) The most common case for this is being able to put a string literal into a `std::string const&` accepting method without difficulty, but there are others. You can disable the behavior by marking `B`'s constructor `explicit`.

Comment: That is true, I guess I just mentally make the connection between a string literal and a `std::string const &` more strongly than I do between two user-generated types

Comment: For a bit of fun, go through your common classes and mark *all* the constructors explicit; the number of failures will show you some interesting tricks your code is using on you. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid and both do the same thing. I'd use the first one because I find the second one confusing, but different strokes for different folks.

EDIT: Actually, I'd do even more than that. I'd mark `B`'s constructor as `explicit` in order to prevent just the sort of thing that makes the second one compile.

Note: I would avoid use of `(void)` in method signatures in C++.

Comment: Explicit helps, but you will have to remove the second argument then and have two constructors - one explicit, one with two arguments. And since C++ still sucks at delegating constructors.. well.. you have to copy-paste a lot.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Good point. Of course you don't need to copy paste too much -- just put the common bits in their own private member function.

Comment: Right, the only problem is - I usually have like 10-20 (if not more) members I really wish to initialize in ctor initialization list.. :( That's why I am falling for C, where you initialize when and how you want it.

Comment: "I would avoid use of (void) in method signatures in C++" -- I've been wondering, why this is frowned upon? Coming from C, I've just always done that without much thought about it. Why is this a C++ 'no-no'?

Comment: @Robert: It's not a no-no in C++, it's just redundant. In C, `(void)` means "A method accepting no parameters", while `()` means "A method accepting an unknown number of parameters". Marking `(void)` can sometimes improve compiler error messages. In C++, `()` and `(void)` are the same, and therefore adding void gives you nothing but extra typing.

Comment: @Vlad: Another good point. I'm +1ing your answer just because of the comments here lol.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. First one explicitly creates `B` instance, and the second one implicitly creates `B` from `A`. I like neither of those. They just increase confusion level and nothing more.

Comment: If you like neither, which alternative would you suggest?

Comment: @BillyONeal: Your alternative with explicit is what I do not to confuse all intern programmers around me. But if we had constructor delegation already supported... it would have been even better.

Comment: Ok, but that is the first example. Explicit just disallows use of the second; the first is still fine. \*Bill is confused...

Comment: Well, the first usage is perfectly clear, right? Just creation of return type with A() as lvalue... Well, I guess making it a constant pointer will prevent the first usage :-D

Comment: I agree the first is perfectly clear, but your answer says you dislike it for some reason.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry :-) I started disliking all these high-level create-temporary-objects for no good reason things lately. I like it small, clean and simple.

Answer (score 1):

I would decorate the constructor as `explicit`, and then use method one as the only available method:

```
class B {
public:
    explicit B(A const & a, int b = 10) : m_a(a), m_i(b) { }
    // ...
};

B foo()  { return B(A()); }
```

That way you can never accidentally construct a `B` from an `A`. If the constructor of `B` is expensive or may throw, then having this extra level of deliberateness in your code may well help make it more readable and less error-prone.